# Law of Demeter and OOP confusion

Tags: asp.net, oop, law-of-demeter

I've been doing some reading recently and have encountered the Law of Demeter. Now some of what I've read makes perfect sense e.g. the paperboy should never be able to rifle through a customers pocket, grab the wallet and take the money out. The wallet is something the customer should have control of, not the [paperboy](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf).

What throws me about the law, maybe I'm just misunderstanding the whole thing, is that stringing properties together with a heirarchy of functionality/information can be so useful. e.g. .NETs HTTPContext class.

Wouldn't code such as :

```
If DataTable.Columns.Count >= 0 Then
   DataTable.Columns(0).Caption = "Something"
End If
```

Or

```
Dim strUserPlatform as string = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Platform.ToString()
```

Or

```
If NewTerm.StartDate >= NewTerm.AcademicYear.StartDate And 
   NewTerm.EndDate <= NewTerm.AcademicYear.EndDate Then
   ' Valid, subject to further tests.
Else
   ' Not valid.
End If
```

be breaking this law? I thought (perhaps mistakenly) the point of OOP was in part to provide access to related classes in a nice heirarchical structure.

I like, for example, the idea of referencing a utility toolkit that can be used by page classes to avoid repetitive tasks, such as sending emails and encapsulating useful string methods:

```
Dim strUserInput As String = "London, Paris, New York"
For Each strSearchTerm In Tools.StringManipulation.GetListOfString(strUserInput, ",")
    Dim ThisItem As New SearchTerm
    ThisItem.Text = strSearchTerm 
Next
```

Any clarity would be great...at the moment I can't reconcile how the law seems to banish stringing properties and methods together...it seems strange to me that so much power should be disregarded? I'm pretty new to OOP as some of you might have guessed, so please go easy :)

Comment: These "laws" aren't true laws. Unlike the laws of thermodynamics you can bend & break them whenever you like. To stop yourself going insane, try to think of it as the "guideline" of Demeter, if you follow it religiously you'll end up working for it, not making it work for you. All things in moderation ... Including moderation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the Law of Demeter (also "Law of Demeter for Functions/Methods") wants to reduce with saying "only use one dot" is that in a method you shouldn't have to assume such a lot of context from the provided arguments. This increases the dependency of the class and makes it less testable.

It doesn't mean that you can't use all of the above examples but it suggests that instead of giving your method the customer which then accesses the wallet and retrieves the money from it:

```
function getPayment(Customer customer)
{
    Money payment = customer.leftpocket.getWallet().getPayment(100);
    ...
    // do stuff with the payment
}
```

that you instead only pass what the paperboy needs to the method and as such reduce the dependency for the method if it's possible:

```
function getPayment(Money money)
{
    // do stuff with the payment
}
```

Your benefit from it will be that you dont depend on the customer to have the wallet in the left pocket but instead just process the money the customer gives you. It's a decision you have to base on your individual case though. Less dependencies allow you to test easier.

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes sense to me that an object shouldn't know too much about another object when its not necessary. Using the first example, other classes such as a Window Cleaner that may slot into that system in future would then have to have the same Money payment = customer.leftpocket.getWallet().getPayment(100) statement, unless you do as suggested and give the customer a getPayment method to start with.

Answer (score 3):

I think applying the Law of Demeter to individual classes is taking it a bit too far.  I think a better application is to apply it to *layers* in your code.  For example, your business logic layer shouldn't need to access anything about the HTTP context, and your data access layer shouldn't need to access anything in the presentation layer.

Yes, it's *usually* good practice to design the interface of your object so that you don't have to do tons of property chaining, but imagine the hideously complex interface you'd have if you tried to do that to the `DataTable` and `HttpContext` classes you gave as examples.

Comment: I agree with both that when designing classes such as the paperboy example, care should be taken to not have a situation where what actually should be customer functionality becomes part of the paperboy, also agree that the layers should be kept seperated in the ways you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The law doesn't say that you shouldn't have access to any information at all in a class, but that you should only have access to information in a way that you can't easily misuse it.

You can for example not add columns in a data table by assigning anything to the `Count` property:

```
DataTable.Columns.Count = 42;
```

Instead you use the `Add` method of the `Columns` object that lets you add a column in a way that all the needed information about the column is there, and also so that the data table get set up with data for that column.